# Unable to build EntityManagerFactory Postgres, Hibernate 5, JPA, EJB's

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am having a problem with Hibernate 5 / JPA , I have problems to solve.

I deploy my application on Jboss EAP 6. + and exceptions are thrown when attempting to build the EntityManagerFactory and MultitenatConnectionProvider

**Stack trace:**

```
19:18:55,265 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 49) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."myProject.war#myDS": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."myProject.war#myDS": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: myDS] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:103)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_65]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_65]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_65]
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.1.Final-redhat-1]
    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: myDS] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:924)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:899)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:76)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:200)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.access$600(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:57)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:99)
        ... 4 more
    Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to instantiate specified multi-tenant connection provider [com.multitenancyprovider.MultiTenantProvider]
        at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.MultiTenantConnectionProviderInitiator.initiateService(MultiTenantConnectionProviderInitiator.java:97)
        at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.MultiTenantConnectionProviderInitiator.initiateService(MultiTenantConnectionProviderInitiator.java:43)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:79)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:201)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:175)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:156)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:228)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:89)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:85)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:184)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:156)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1825)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1783)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:96)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:914)
        ... 9 more
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

      <persistence-unit name="myDS" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>java:/myDS</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.general.entities.AccountingDocumentType</class>
        <class>com.general.entities.AccountingOperation</class>

        <properties>
                <property name="hibernate.multiTenancy" value="SCHEMA"/>
                <property name="hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver" value="com.multitenancyprovider.SchemaResolver"/>
                <property name="hibernate.multi_tenant_connection_provider" value="com.multitenancyprovider.MultiTenantProvider"/>
                <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
                <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
                <property name="org.hibernate.type" value="debug" />
                <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" />
                <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" />
                <property name="hibernate.cache.infinispan.statistics" value="false" />
                <property name="hibernate.order_inserts" value="true"/>
                <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="20"/>
                <!-- Turn on entity and query cache statistics in the admin console -->
                <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="false" />
                <!-- store entries in the cache in a more human friendly format - helps when interpreting logs -->
                <property name="hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries" value="false" />
                <!-- MultiTenancy -->           
        </properties>    

      </persistence-unit>
    </persistence>
```

**MultiTenantProvider.java**

```
public class MultiTenantProvider implements MultiTenantConnectionProvider, ServiceRegistryAwareService {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private DataSource dataSource;

    public boolean supportsAggressiveRelease() {
        return false;
    }

    public void injectServices(ServiceRegistryImplementor serviceRegistry) {
        try {
            final Context init = new InitialContext();
            dataSource = (DataSource) init.lookup("java:/MyDS");
        } catch (final NamingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public boolean isUnwrappableAs(Class clazz) {
        return false;
    }

    public <T> T unwrap(Class<T> clazz) {
        return null;
    }

    public Connection getAnyConnection() throws SQLException {
        final Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
        return connection;
    }

    public Connection getConnection(String tenantIdentifier) throws SQLException {
        final Connection connection = getAnyConnection();
        try {
            connection.createStatement().execute("SET SCHEMA '" + tenantIdentifier + "'");
        } catch (final SQLException e) {
            throw new HibernateException("Could not alter JDBC connection to specified schema [" + tenantIdentifier + "]", e);
        }
        return connection;
    }

    public void releaseAnyConnection(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        try {
            connection.createStatement().execute("SET SCHEMA 'public'");
        } catch (final SQLException e) {
            throw new HibernateException("Could not alter JDBC connection to specified schema [public]", e);
        }
        connection.close();
    }

    public void releaseConnection(String tenantIdentifier, Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        releaseAnyConnection(connection);
    }
}
```

**standalone.xml / dataSource**

```
<datasource jta="false" jndi-name="java:/MyDS" pool-name="MyDS" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres</connection-url>
                    <driver-class>org.postgresql.Driver</driver-class>
                    <driver>postgresql-9.4.1209.jre6.jar</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>postgres</user-name>
                        <password>cyberlink</password>
                    </security>
                    <validation>
                        <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
                        <background-validation>false</background-validation>
                    </validation>
                    <timeout>
                        <set-tx-query-timeout>false</set-tx-query-timeout>
                        <blocking-timeout-millis>0</blocking-timeout-millis>
                        <idle-timeout-minutes>0</idle-timeout-minutes>
                        <query-timeout>0</query-timeout>
                        <use-try-lock>0</use-try-lock>
                        <allocation-retry>0</allocation-retry>
                        <allocation-retry-wait-millis>0</allocation-retry-wait-millis>
                    </timeout>
                    <statement>
                        <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
                    </statement>
                </datasource>
```

I followed this example on this page and implement the test project shown on the web: https://www.toptal.com/hibernate/build-multitenant-java-hibernate , this problem comes when I want to implement multi-tenancy in a personal project.